# Why won't my for loop subtract from a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm trying to make a super-simple, text-based boxing game as a practice exercise. I want each pass through the loop to throw a punch and inflict a random amount of damage. Each punch will hit a random part of the opponent. 
However, the damage never gets subtracted from the original amount.
Where did I go wrong?

Here is my code and output for a couple of rounds.

```
#starting stats
nose = 100
jaw = 100
face = 100
head = 100
hp = nose + jaw + face + head
moral = 200
import random

#fight
for fight in range(10):
    if hp <= 0:
        print("DING DING DING\nKNOCK OUT\nYOU ARE THE WINNER!!!!!!")
    if hp <= 25:
        moral - 25
        print("He's losing moral!")
    if moral <=0:
        hp - 75
        print("He's about to KO!!!")
    if hp> 0:
        print("=========\nMORAL:{0}\nHP:{1}\nNOSE:{2}\nJAW:{3}\nFACE:{4}\nHEAD:{5}\n=========".format(moral, hp, nose, jaw, face, head))
        move = input('TYPE "P" TO THOW A PUNCH!!!')
        if move == "p" or "P" or "PUNCH":
            part = int(random.randint(1,4))
            damage = int(random.randint(1, 100))
            if part == 1:
                print("PUNCH TO THE NOSE!!!")
                nose - damage
            elif part == 2:
                print("PUNCH TO THE JAW!!!")
                jaw - damage
            elif part == 3:
                print("PUNCH TO THE FACE!!!")
                face - damage
            elif part == 4:
                print("PUNCH TO THE HEAD!!!")
                head - damage
```

Output:

```
=========
MORAL:200
HP:400
NOSE:100
JAW:100
FACE:100
HEAD:100
=========
TYPE "P" TO THOW A PUNCH!!!P
PUNCH TO THE HEAD!!!
=========
MORAL:200
HP:400
NOSE:100
JAW:100
FACE:100
HEAD:100
=========
TYPE "P" TO THOW A PUNCH!!!P
PUNCH TO THE HEAD!!!
=========
MORAL:200
HP:400
NOSE:100
JAW:100
FACE:100
HEAD:100
=========
TYPE "P" TO THOW A PUNCH!!!
```

Comment: There's a fully mature [boxing game](http://webl.vivi.com/) to use for comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statements like `moral - 25` don't do anything at all; they subtract one value from another but then discard the result. You actually need to assign the result back to your variable:

```
moral = moral - 25
```

which can be shortened to

```
moral -= 25
```

Answer (score 1):

You neglect to save the result.  Try this:

```
    hp = hp - 75
```

Better yet, use the short-hand:

```
    hp -= 75
```

Answer (score 1):

`hp - 75` never resets the variable. With this in mind, `hp` will always be the global value of `400`. Use the `-=` syntax to accomplish this:

```
hp -= 75
```